# How to determine original folder in SVN.

Tags: svn

I just realized that I accidentally copied a folder from one place to another. My problem is that I dont remember which folder is the original and which is they copy. I mucked around in both folders since then, so I cant use the date modified. How can I use svn to figure out which folder is the original?

Answer (score 0):

For each of the two folders, run `svn log --stop-on-copy`. The one that goes further back in time is the original.

Comment: They both went back to the initial import. I figured out my answer a different way though, thanks.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Post your own answer and tell us how please?

Comment: @Rup I looked at a friend's checkout of the same repo :D.

Comment: If they both go back to the initial import, then you didn't perform a true `svn cp` to make the copy, or you did it before you imported to the repository.